# Spring Boot: Failed to load ApplicationContext when running a test

Tags: spring-boot

I inherited an old legacy application where all the integration tests are annotated with `@Ignore`. When removing the annotation, a simple test fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionResolver': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'organizationService';...
```

Here is how a test is defined:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SubsidiaryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SubsidiaryService subsidiaryService;

    @Test
    public void checkSpringSetupForTests() throws JSONException {
        String actual = "{\"id\": 123, \"name\": \"John\"}";
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(
                "{\"id\": 123, \"name\": \"John\"}", actual, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnNotFoundResponse() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/subsidiary/0000"))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out the reason for the failure without success.
I also noted that in this multi-module project, the parent pom defines the spring-boot-starter-parent as follows:

```xml
<groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-root</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>xxx-root</name>
    <description>bla-bla</description>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

Usually, I declared the `spring-boot-starter-parent` in every child module `pom.xml` in its `<parent>` section leaving the root `pom.xml` to contain just the list of child modules. But in this project, the child `pom.xml` declares as parent the parent project itself as follows:

```xml
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>XXX-root</artifactId>
        <version>X.X.X-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
<dependecies>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
</dependecies>
```

Is it wrong? Any other clues?

If I remove `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` in the test class, the failure is gone, but the instance of `mockMvc` is null.

As for the available classes annotated with `@Configuration`, there are some of them, located all in the root package:

```java
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class MyWebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
...
}

@Configuration
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyWebApplication.class);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
...
```

The full stack trace is avalable in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/2b8dc1a377ae2881d610e753a15481ca) which contains 2 files:

- a standard stack trace output
- the same but with `debug: true` setting in the `application.yaml` file.

What is really weird is that the web-app starts correctly and I can even see the `mailSender` bean initialized:

```
MailHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.defaults.enabled is considered true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'mailSender' (OnBeanCondition)
```

Comment: it is hard to tell exactly how this might be fixed given the information provided.  You inherited a test that is using \@ContextConfiguration without any parameters.  This will cause Spring to look for static inner \@Configuration class in your test class.  Does an static inner class exist?

Comment: Just updated the post content about that.

Comment: Well the error tells you what to do. There is no `organizationService` it might be that there is an even longer stacktrace. Also the `WebConfig` is "wrong" as it has `@EnableWebMvc` which disables parts of the Spring Boot auto config. The `ServletInitializer` doesn't need to be an `@Configuration` if you deploy a war it will be detected automatically. The `@SpringBootApplication` is already an `@Configuration` so that can go as well.

Comment: Hmm, besides `organizationService` there are plenty of other errors like `Error creating bean with name <beanName>:`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field <name>` event after applying the modifications suggested by @M.Deinum.

Comment: In one of the child modules I also found this dependency= `<artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId><optional>true</optional>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an implementation of `OrganizationService` to `@ContextConfiguration`. The following example should solve the issue if `OrganizationServiceImpl` is an implementation of `OrganizationService`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        OrganizationServiceImpl.class })
```

If `OrganizationService` is a class, the following will do:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        OrganizationService.class })
```

Comment: Where should this annotation be added (test class, SoringBoot app class, other)? The problem is that in this case, multiple services should be declared/added this way to the context configuration. See the link to the gist above which contains the full stack trace.